# excel cell hyperlink to the same cell

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

version：Excel2010
sheet1's Region C2:C100
I want that
       C2 hyperlink to C2;
       C3 hyperlink to C3;
       ...
       C100 hyperlink to C100.

cell C2’s step：
Select C2-Righ-create hyperlink-place in this document under link to-
-Enter the Address of the Same cell:C2-Text Display:C2

from C2 Autofill down to C100，all of the hyperlink's address are C2,
and all the text diasplay are also C2.

I donot want use function of Hyperlink.

Can anyone help me solute it,THS.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] for information on how to modify your answer to best suit the format of this site. By doing this it is easier for us to provide you with a high quality answer as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells you wish to fill and then run:

```
Sub HyperAdder()
   For Each r In Selection
      ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:="", SubAddress:=r.Parent.Name & "!" & r.Address(0, 0), TextToDisplay:="myself"
   Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: It works.Thank you very much.You are the best man I have met.